# When i write a logical operator in list to find what key word i want but is a little weird

Tags: python, list, for-loop, logical-operators

I have a List_1 like this

```
List_1 = ['1_1.jpg','1_1_right.jpg','1_1_left.jpg','1_2.jpg','1_2_right.jpg','1_2_left.jpg']
```

And i use the following code to take specific string I want

```
List_2 = [i for i in List_1 if 'left'or'right' in i]
```

but it still give me the same List as following

```
List_2 = ['1_1.jpg','1_1_right.jpg','1_1_left.jpg','1_2.jpg','1_2_right.jpg','1_2_left.jpg']
```

Actually, what i want is like this

```
List_2 = ['1_1_right.jpg','1_1_left.jpg','1_2_right.jpg','1_2_left.jpg']
```

Comment: `if 'left'or'right' in i` is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to use list comprehension? You could also use a regular for loop for this:

```
List_1 = ['1_1.jpg','1_1_right.jpg','1_1_left.jpg','1_2.jpg','1_2_right.jpg','1_2_left.jpg']

expected = []

for i in List_1:
    if 'left' in i or 'right' in i:
        expected.append(i)

print(expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how `or` works in Python, you have to complete the full condition first.

`if 'left' or 'right' in i` is actually, `if 'left' or ('right' in i)`

Try with:

```
if ('left' in i) or ('right' in i)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question!
It work !!!